# Read data in file from powershell

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I have a file with data that looks in this pattern.

```
[hashtable[]]$Counties = 
@(
@{"County1" = @{"City"="New York"
                "State"="NY"
                }
},
@{"County2" = @{"City"="Miami"
                "State"="FL"
                }
},
@{"County3" = @{"City"="Orlando"
                "State"="FL"
                }
}
)
```

My goal is to read the file that has this data and loop for each county (county1, county2 etc) and read the city and state for each county.

I am struggling to write a PowerShell script that does this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Expected output

```
Name    City     State
County1 New York NY
County2 Miami FL
County3 Orlando FL
```

Comment: Shouldn't [Import-PowerShellDataFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile?view=powershell-7.3) do the job?  ... or at least a big part of it ... ‍♂️

Comment: When you say that you have a file with that data, why are you using this format? Why not store your data as a Json instead ? Do you need it this way for something specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I propose that you should store your data as [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) instead of a hashtable literal, unless you have a very specific need to store your data as you have right now. JSON is quite easy to read and also easy to edit, it has been also proved to be a very robust format to store and transport data. There are also several free and even open-source editors that support the Json format, for instance, [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/).

```json
[
  {
    "County1": {
      "City": "New York",
      "State": "NY"
    }
  },
  {
    "County2": {
      "City": "Miami",
      "State": "FL"
    }
  },
  {
    "County3": {
      "City": "Orlando",
      "State": "FL"
    }
  }
]
```

If you opt for this format, importing your data and transforming it into the output you expect would look like this:

```bash
$Counties = Get-Content path\to\jsonfile.json -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
foreach ($county in $Counties) {
    foreach ($property in $county.PSObject.Properties) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            County = $property.Name
            City   = $property.Value.City
            State  = $property.Value.State
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
County  City     State
------  ----     -----
County1 New York NY
County2 Miami    FL
County3 Orlando  FL
```

Answer (score 1):

The example you are presenting is a **PowerShell expression**.
You might simply put the value (at the right-hand-side of the equality operator) in to a PowerShell file:

```
@'
@(
@{"County1" = @{"City"="New York"
                "State"="NY"
                }
},
@{"County2" = @{"City"="Miami"
                "State"="FL"
                }
},
@{"County3" = @{"City"="Orlando"
                "State"="FL"
                }
}
)
'@ | Set-Content .\Data.ps1
```

For later use by invoking the expression via the PowerShell dot sourcing

> ##### [Script scope and dot sourcing](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_scripts#script-scope-and-dot-sourcing)
>
> The dot sourcing feature lets you run a script in the current scope instead of in the script scope. When you run a script that is dot sourced, the commands in the script run as though you had typed them at the command prompt. The functions, variables, aliases, and drives that the script creates are created in the scope in which you are working. After the script runs, you can use the created items and access their values in your session.

```
$Countries = . .\Data.ps1
$Countries

Name                           Value
----                           -----
County1                        {[City, New York], [State, NY]}
County2                        {[City, Miami], [State, FL]}
County3                        {[City, Orlando], [State, FL]}
```

To "*loop for each county (county1, county2 etc) and read the city and state for each county*" in your specific structure, you will need to:

- Loop through the array

  - Enumerate the keys and/or values of the hash table

    - Enumerate the keys and/or values of the country table

```
$Countries | Foreach-Object {
    $Properties = @{}
    $_.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
        $Properties['Country'] = $_.Name
        $_.Value.GetEnumerator() | Foreach-Object {
            $Properties[$_.Name] = $_.Value
        }
    }
    [PSCustomObject]$Properties
}

State Country City
----- ------- ----
NY    County1 New York
FL    County2 Miami
FL    County3 Orlando
```

As correctly commented by [**Olaf**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9196560/olaf), the example you present is close to a [PowerShell Data File](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_data_files) which might be safely imported with the `Import-PowerShellDataFile` cmdlet using the PowerShell 
[ConstrainedLanguage mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_language_modes#constrainedlanguage-mode).

> ##### [`Import-PowerShellDataFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-powershelldatafile)
>
> The `Import-PowerShellDataFile` cmdlet safely imports key-value pairs from hashtables defined in a `.PSD1` file. The values could be imported using `Invoke-Expression` on the contents of the file. However, `Invoke-Expression` runs any code contained in the file. This could produce unwanted results or execute unsafe code. `Import-PowerShellDataFile` imports the data without invoking the code. By default there is a 500 key limit, but this can be bypassed with the **SkipLimitCheck** switch.

```
@'
@{Countries =
        @{County1 = @{
                City = 'New York'
                State = 'NY'
            }},
        @{County2 = @{
                City = 'Miami'
                State = 'FL'
            }},
        @{County3 = @{
                City = 'Orlando'
                State = 'FL'
            }}}
'@ | Set-Content .\Data.psd1
$Data = Import-PowerShellDataFile .\data.psd1
$Data.Countries # | Foreach-Object { ...
```

**Notes**

- a **PowerShell Data File** starts with a hash table (`@{ ... }`)
- in most cases it is [not required quote keys in a hash table](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable)
- there isn't a native "[serializer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization)" for the PowerShell syntax (something like `$Data |` [`ConvertTo-Expression`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ConvertTo-Expression)) which does in fact exist for other languages as `Json` as suggested in the helpful answer from [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon)